# Regex to match sentences from facebook posts and comments

Tags: python, regex, facebook

I'm looking to get a regex working in python that captures all of the message within a facebook post but then STOPS (instead of returning the rest of the JSON textline).

I know the specific field that occurs after EVERYTHING in the comment message field. I want the regex to stop there but can't get it working.

So, to be as concise as possible, how do I set a regex to STOP the match when it hits the following group of characters?

`\su'type'` (e.g. preceeded by a single whitespace character.)

thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You capture everything before it:

```
re.search(r'^(.*?)stuff', text).group(1)
```

This will stop at the first occurrence of `stuff`. If you make it greedy, it will stop at the last:

```
re.search(r'^(.*)stuff', text).group(1)
```

Comment: thanks, the answer was to read it as a json instead of regex string matching...but thanks for your help !